# Kernel died with exit code 1(VS code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is the error message displayed when I run the code in Interactive window in vs code:

C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2195: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Unicode is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' – or use CUnicode. warn( C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2150: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '8fe74386-11f1-4831-b37d-5582442edf8a' instead of 'b"8fe74386-11f1-4831-b37d-5582442edf8a"'. warn( Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.5.702919634\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers..\pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in  runpy.run_path(module, run_name="**main**") File "F:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, File "F:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code _r...

---

I tried re-installing VS code (In another DRIVE F:).
I am using python(conda) interpreter.

Comment: Same error here:


`
Kernel died with exit code 1. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryan\Miniconda3\envs\col1\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\ryan\Miniconda3\envs\col1\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
...
  File "C:\Users\ryan\Miniconda3\envs\col1\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
`

Comment: I tried reinstalling anaconda and vscode.

Comment: and also try running vscode from anaconda prompt shell with admin privileges.. type 'code' in the shell and hit enter. VSCode automatically starts and then press Ctrl+Shift+P amd select python(conda) interpreter. This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was resolved on its own. Maybe it was because the Conda environment was just created and VS Code for some reason couldn't start Jupyter notebook. Once I started Jupyter notebook from conda, it may have resolved the issue for VS Code too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This fix it from terminal*

`pip install pywin32==228`

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==228 (from versions: 302, 303, 304)

Answer (score 9):

Also a solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5689):

```
conda install ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 3):

1-Open Vs code choose your Kernal and Reinstall ipykenel

(Don't press anything keep reinstall till it works)
**Keep your kernal open while you doing this step by opening any notebook in the browser using Jupiter notebook normally** And it will Work

or

Go to terminal open it as admin.

- conda activate base
- conda install --name base ipykernel -y
- refresh the kernel by opening the jupyter note book from vscode
  terminal
- -Choose the kernal you updated with ipykernel in vscode

this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

***Issue:***

**Kernel died with exit code 1073741845**.

**1.** c:\anaconda\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\traitlets\ **traitlets.py** :2196: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Unicode is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' – or use CUnicode.

**2.** warn( c:\anaconda\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2151: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in **traitlets** 5.0. Use '7aa5b615-129a-4e47-b483-0954be3b7001' instead of 'b"7aa5b615-129a-4e47-b483-0954be3b7001"'.

**3.** warn( Bad file descriptor (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100)

***Solution:***

To solve 1. & 2. using the following commend in vscode python terminal:

**python -m pip install traitlets==4.3.3 --force-reinstall** (maybe need run 2 times and shows successfully install)

just reinstall the traitlets to the lower version.

To solve 3. using the following commend in vscode python terminal:

**python -m pip install pyzmq==19.0.2 --force-reinstall**  (maybe need run 2 times and shows successfully install)

just reinstall the pyzmq to the lower version.

Comment: This should be the right solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Another package fails with error saying it requires traitlets>=5 version to run.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what THE TECHIE HAND recommended- I opened a python terminal in VS Code and launched jupyter notebook from there. It opened in my web browser and allowed me to set a python 3 kernel, which then enabled Jupyter to work in VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

Open your VS code, uninstall Python and Jupyter  extensions and reinstall them again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by:

1. Opening Anaconda Navigator
2. Switching to the correct conda environment with the menu at the top
3. Opening VS Code from the Anaconda navigator

For some reason, this made the interactive window work again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has occured to me as well , In my case I had code.py file removing it had seemed to have solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with VS Code. Issue got fixed by

1. Uninstalling Anaconda
2. Removing Anaconda from `/opt` and `~/opt` ([credits / video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAYjrSg5CHw))
3. Reinstalling Anaconda.

---

**Important Note** - I assume this issue was with `IPython 8.1.1`. After reinstall  from an existing package the version changed to `7.29.0` with `Python 3.9.7` and it works.