# 'Kernel died with exit code 1' Error with Jupyter Notebook in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, vscode-python

I am trying to run a Jupyter notebook in VS Code but I keep getting this error code:
[image]

I have Python 3.8.8 which was installed using Anaconda. The project folder has a virtual environment created using venv. I tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67036168/kernel-died-with-exit-code-1vs-code) but none worked.

Comment: Can you share out (maybe post as a file link, since it can be very large) the contents of the Jupyter section of the VS Code output window? I might be able to help debug this.

Comment: Here's the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13PB9lgFq2AJoXEFixoa-uc3xNmgpIfbM/view?usp=sharing