# Jupyter notebook cell code not executing in VSCode when there is a file named random.py in the folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have just started using Jupyter notebooks in VSCode and have come across a strange issue. I made a folder for keeping my lab programs and there is a file named random.py in the folder. When I try to execute a code cell of my Jupyter notebook which is present in the same folder then I get an error 'Kernel died with exit code 1'. If I delete the contents of the random.py file and just make it an empty file then also the issue persists. The issue is resolved if I remove the file named random.py or change it's name to something else like random1.py.

I have read about 'Kernel died with exit code 1' error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67036168/kernel-died-with-exit-code-1vs-code) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5689).

My Environment data

- VS Code version: 1.59.0
- Jupyter Extension version: v2021.8.1236758218
- Python Extension version: v2021.8.1105858891
- OS: Windows 10
- Python version: 3.8.5 64-bit
- Type of virtual environment
  used: Global (I am not completely sure but this is the environment
  based on the vscode docs that I've read on python environments) Here
  is the image to make this clear - [image showing that I don't have
  any 'base: conda' or something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dng5f.jpg)
- Jupyter server running: Local

I do not have Anaconda installed on my system. I tried the fixes told in the above links but none of them worked. If I put the Jupyter notebook in any other folder and run the cell code then it runs perfectly fine. I want to know that is it possible for a Jupyter notebook to not run when there's a file named 'random.py' present in the same folder? I have not seen this issue reported anywhere else so I am putting it here so that I can get some help on it.

Here are the screenshots for the proof -

1. [not working when random.py file is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S9Cq.jpg)
2. [working when the filename is changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1XWY.jpg)

Here is the complete error message -

Kernel died with exit code 1. Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in 
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_*init**.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 12, in 
import jupyter_client
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client_*init**.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 16, in 
import tempfile
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in 
from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' from 'random' (d:\LABS\AI Lab\lab3\random.py)

Comment: `random` is a built-in python library, this might be the reason for it. try renaming it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Renaming does solve the issue but I want to know the reason due to which this is happening.

Comment: Can you paste the error - It says ```kernel``` died

Comment: The last 2 error messages were hidden in the `...`. I didn't know that upon copying the text they would be visible. Had I seen them earlier then I could've guessed that the file random.py is indeed interfering and causing the whole issue. Thank you for making me paste the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're interfering with python's built in 'random' module and something is accidentally importing your file instead of the proper module. That is why the solution is changing the name of your file.

Comment: I tried importing the random module in a python file in the same folder and I think what you are saying is absolutely correct. I used the random.shuffle() function but I am getting this error `AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'shuffle'`. Upon renaming the file the shuffle funtion is working fine.