# Kernel crashed while running a cell of .ipynb file in VS Code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following message from jupyter log:

error 0:13:42.793: Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: /home/michael/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2392: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
warn(
/home/michael/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2346: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'b86ba372-5124-43f6-a937-9633ae2d7032' instead of 'b"b86ba372-5124-43f6-a937-9633ae2d7032"'.
warn(

error 0:13:42.816: Raw kernel process exited code: undefined

I tried looking at [Kernel died with exit code 1(VS code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67036168/kernel-died-with-exit-code-1vs-code) but they use windows. I'm using python 3.8.10 in WSL Ubuntu. So this won't work: `pip install pywin32==228`. Downgrading traitlets also causes all kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5963) on github.

You can try reinstall `Pyzmq==19.0.2`.

Hope this can help.