# "Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell" while using tokenize

Tags: python, jupyter, nltk

I am trying to tokenize strings (rather long strings from 10-K reports) for a dataset with 56252 observations. However, the kernel keeps crashing usually about a quarter of the way through the dataset.

I tried:

1. Running the .py file without Jupyter and receive the error: `zsh: killed`
2. Simply using `line[j].split(' ')` instead of `word_tokenize(line[j])` (below)
3. Reinstalling python and jupyter.

Nothing seems to have worked, therefore, any feedback would be appreciated.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

output = [[20120831,20120808,1199,1928175839, 'words section one report', 'words section onea report', 'words section seven report'],[20150621,20141231,1239,1124966666, 'more words fly kite big', 'different words compared section before', 'even more different words']]

item_1 = []
item_1a = []
item_7 = []

count = 0
for line in output:
    try:
        item_entry = []
        item_tokens_to_add = []
        for i in range(0, 4):
            item_entry.append(line[i])
        for j in range(4, 7):
            line_tokens = word_tokenize(line[j])
            item_tokens_to_add.append(line_tokens)
        item_1.append(item_entry + item_tokens_to_add[0])
        item_1a.append(item_entry + item_tokens_to_add[1])
        item_7.append(item_entry + item_tokens_to_add[2])
        count += 1
    except:
        pass
    print(str(count) + '/' + str(len(output)))
```

Here is some information from the Jupyter log:

```
error 12:27:24.797: Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2202: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
  warn(
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2157: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '0a146f2b-abdf-428e-b31f-d08fde1c7026' instead of 'b"0a146f2b-abdf-428e-b31f-d08fde1c7026"'.
  warn(
```

I have actually removed all punctuation in the text hence I don't know why I'm getting an error message describing "extra quotes". Also, the kernel crashes at different observations.

Comment: I don't think it's the code... runs fine on my Mac's Jupyter instance. I'm surprised a 'warning' is killing your kernel. Though a source online recommends trying `pip install pywin32==228`
Just to be sure, are you keeping an eye on your RAM useage when you run it? How much RAM do you have on your machine?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9347

Comment: @k-w-cooper Thanks for your reply. I have 8 GB of RAM and only have VSCode open and nothing else. I believe I shut down most background processes and there's about 3GB memory free. I tried `pip install pywin32==228` but that did not resolve it either.

Comment: try `conda install ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall`

Comment: ie. from this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67036168/kernel-died-with-exit-code-1vs-code

Comment: Thanks, with kernel crashes it never hurts to rule out ram. The conclusion from both discussions is that the traitlets bug has to do something with dependancies between ipython and VSCode.

Comment: @k-w-cooper The traitlets bug seems to be the issue. After downgrading to version 4.3.3, it still crashes and led to the kernel not starting. I went through some steps to get the kernel to start and that ultimately comes down to upgrading traitlets back to 5.1.1. Similarly, I tried to reinstall pyzmq to version 19.2.0 but that doesn't work either. Also tried `!echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the terminal. Anyway, thanks for your input!

Comment: fwiw, I got the same error but the reason for kernel crush was that the RAM was too small. Upgrading RAM size fixed it.