# What can I do about Jupyter returning error for no clear reason?

Tags: python, conda, jupyter, importerror

I had been doing a ML course where we had to use conda + anaconda.

In the course, they start up jupyter through the terminal, which for some reason I couldn't do. So I started using the `microsoft` extension for `jupyter notebooks`. It worked okay for some time until an error popped up under this cell:

```py
import pandas as pd
```

The error:

```
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

I don't know what has happened. It worked before perfectly. Please provide an answer if possible. I will be grateful for any response.

**Edit**

Jupyter Log:

```
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
16:53:58.987 [info] Restarted cfc82026-4df4-42b3-a6cc-a6aa07b76e56
16:53:59.370 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 0 @ 1701392039369
16:53:59.717 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: 0.02s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.

16:53:59.717 [info] Dispose Kernel process 13930.
16:53:59.773 [info] End cell 0 execution @ undefined, started @ 1701392039369, elapsed time = -1701392039.369s
16:54:26.617 [info] Handle Execution of Cells 0 for ~/Desktop/machine_learning/project_1/Untitled.ipynb
```

**EDIT *2.0***

The kernel always crashes when it contains `import pandas`.

Comment: Possibly related [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73608201](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73608201/kernel-crashed-while-executing-code-in-the-the-current-cell-or-a-previous-cell#comment130600599_73608201) , i.e. check exceeded RAM usage

Comment: I don't it is the ram because I don't have any other program open and I have 4 sticks of 4GB RAM