# Bad file descriptor (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:145) Vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm facing this problem whenever i open a new ipynb file in vscode
the error is

i tried reinstalling pyzmq and jupyter notebook but none of them works
and if i reload the vscode window multiple times the code executes
this error troubling me a lot
kindly help me in resolving this issue

```
08:20:02.960 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 991, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 113, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
08:20:02.963 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 635, in initialize
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 241, in write_connection_file
    write_connection_file(cf, ip=self.ip, key=self.session.key, transport=self.transport,
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 164, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 142, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 985, in secure_write
    with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o0600), mode, encoding=encoding) as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
08:20:02.966 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process Bad file descriptor (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:145)
08:20:02.999 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 1073741845, Reason: c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2538: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
  warn(
c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2489: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'ac8ae820-e112-41c5-a9db-a06d87f6208c' instead of 'b"ac8ae820-e112-41c5-a9db-a06d87f6208c"'.
  warn(
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 991, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 113, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 635, in initialize
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 241, in write_connection_file
    write_connection_file(cf, ip=self.ip, key=self.session.key, transport=self.transport,
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 164, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 142, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 985, in secure_write
    with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o0600), mode, encoding=encoding) as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Bad file descriptor (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:145)
```

someone kindly help me in solving this issue

i tried reinstalling pyzmq and jupyter notebook but none of them works
and if i reload the vscode window multiple times the code executes
this error troubling me a lot
kindly help me in resolving this issue

Comment: this happens with an empty notebook? If not, provide a [mre]

Comment: similar first error messages: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/728, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084149/11107541. Do any of those help?